# Can't get past choose partition on Windows 8 boot camp install. Then can't remove incomplete installation

Tags: windows, bootcamp, install

So I got a new shiny sparkling MacBook Pro retina and Windows 8 just downloaded from MSDNAA. Reading success stories on the web that this runs even though Boot camp says Windows 7 makes me want to try it.

I start the boot camp assistant and run through the wizard with all options checked, creating a USB installation media.

During the windows installation I get to the point where I choose which partition to install to, but I get the error message "Windows can't be installed on drive 0 partition 4".
Yes, I have clicked on drive options and then on format, but I still get the same error message.

Not getting anywhere I reboot back to Mac OS X and run the Boot camp assistant again with the hope of starting over and try again. The only availilable option in Boot camp is to remove Windows and restore the hard drive to a single volume. Fair enough. However, the computer only gets to "Status: partitioning hard drive" where it sits for hours (5 and counting). Computer still responsive, but boot camp assistant does nothing. I quitted the boot camp assistant, which it allowed without having to use force shutdown and without questions about whether I really want to quit the program during hard drive partitioning.

One annoying thing is that when booting the computer defaults to Windows, so I have to press the Alt key and choose the Mac OS X partition manually.

Anyone who has any ideas as of how to

- get Windows 8 installation past the select partition screen?
- get Boot camp to remove the Windows partition without freezing so I can give it another go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it (at least the parts in my question) working:

- Reboot
- Reboot again
- Run boot camp and remove old installation (this time it worked)
- Reboot
- Run boot camp and start Windows installation
- At the choose partition screen, choose the boot camp partition, select Drive options, and then select Format.

I wonder why it worked this time, but not the first.
Now I get a error message of corrupt files however. Guess I have to download the DVD image from MSDNAA again.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't take the 'reboot, reboot, run bootcamp, reboot ... path. I did this instead: at that error message 'Windows can't be installed on drive ...', I just selected the BootCamp partition and clicked 'Format'. I got no feedback, but I chose next right afterwards and the Windows 10 installation continued normally.